# Split on unescaped spaces

Tags: java, regex, string

I've got strings in the form of:

```
/path/ /path\ with\ space/ /another/
```

I need to split this so I end up with an array containing:

```
[ /path/, /path with space/, /another/ ]
```

Is there an easy regex that would take care of this? Previously I was using \s+ but obviously that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

```
String s = "/path/ /path\\ with\\ space/ /another/";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<!\\\\)\\s+");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
// prints [/path/, /path\ with\ space/, /another/]
```

Note that the second element still contains `\`s, which you'll need to strip out yourself.

```
for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++)
{
    parts[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("\\\\ ", " ");
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
// prints [/path/, /path with space/, /another/]
```

Yes, that's **four** `\`s just to match a single one in the string.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting, didn't know if split worked with lookbehinds like this. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

What if you split it on the and "/ " (note the space) and append a forward slash after each match? I'm not sure if split will work with a lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `[/](w|s)+[/]` ?